# Python pandas: merge column values if not None (join string), and then only keep first row

Tags: python, merge, pandas-groupby

Here is representative data

```
asker1 = ['Peter', 'Markus', 'Rebecca', None, None, None, None, 'Sofie', 'Jesus', None]
que_text = ['QQQ', 'RRR', 'GGG', 'GGG', None, None, None, None, 'WWW', 'AAA']
date = ['14.10.2001', '12. October 1999', '14.10.2004', '14.10.2002', '14.10.2002', '14.10.2002', '14.10.2002', '14.10.2010', '14.10.2000', '14.10.2000']
identifier = ['Drs_2_00028_1', 'Drs_2_00029_1', 'Drs_2_00030_1_KlAnfr_000.tif', 'Drs_2_00030_1_KlAnfr_001.tif', 'Drs_2_00030_1_KlAnfr_002.tif', 'Drs_2_00030_1_KlAnfr_003.tif', 'Drs_2_00030_1_KlAnfr_004.tif', 'Drs_2_00052_1', 'Drs_2_00054_1_KlAnfr_000.tif', 'Drs_2_00054_1_KlAnfr_001.tif']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    list(zip(asker1, que_text, date, identifier)),
    columns =['asker1', 'que_text', 'date', 'identifier']
)
```

I am extracting textual information from single file pictures in a folder. Some of these pictures are connected, meaning they represent subsequent pages(`000`=first page; `001`=second page) but not all of them are connected to another file.

I read the information i want for each file as a row in my pandas `df2`.

**My goal** is to merge each second(`001`)/third(`002`)/fourth(`003`)/... `que_text` value to its first page(`000`) row('que_text'), as long as the value isn't `None`. The `'identifier'` column contains the following char sequence if the row(file) is connected to another row(file): `_KlAnfr_\d{3}.tif`

Why merge only `que_text` value? Since i created the dataframe from regexes, that match certain words at the beginning and end of the raw string, they fail to match for every second/third/forth/... page as the unique starting words that regex would capture are missing (because i have treated each file separately, so far).

For example row nine and ten (both being connected by identifier col): I would like to have one string `'WWW AAA'` (`merged 'que_text[8]=WWW' and que_text[9]=AAA`), in order to try to match using regex (again) subsequently

After merging the respective `que_text`-values all rows except the first should be dropped, i.e., only the one with the number `000` should be kept.

The expected result for the sample is:

```
    asker1 que_text              date                    identifier
0    Peter      QQQ        14.10.2001                 Drs_2_00028_1
1   Markus      RRR  12. October 1999                 Drs_2_00029_1
2  Rebecca  GGG GGG        14.10.2004  Drs_2_00030_1_KlAnfr_000.tif
3    Sofie     None        14.10.2010                 Drs_2_00052_1
4    Jesus  WWW AAA        14.10.2000  Drs_2_00054_1_KlAnfr_000.tif
```

Comment: As you've proposed in the comment below: I've edited the question. Just roll it back, if you don't like it.

Comment: perfect, i think the headline is misleading

Comment: I've adjusted it a bit, but am not sure if it's better this way?

Comment: i thinks thats better, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
def merge_qts(sdf):
    sdf.que_text = " ".join(
        str(qt) for _, qt in sorted(zip(sdf.No, sdf.que_text))
        if qt is not None
    )
    return sdf

mask = df2.identifier.str.contains(r"_KlAnfr_\d{3}\.tif$")
df3 = df2.loc[mask, ["que_text", "identifier"]]
pattern = r"^(.*?_KlAnfr)_(\d{3}).tif$"
df3[["ID", "No"]] = df2.identifier.str.extract(pattern)
df2.loc[mask, "que_text"] = df3.groupby("ID").apply(merge_qts).que_text
df2 = df2[~df2.identifier.str.contains(r"_KlAnfr_\d{2}[1-9]\.tif$")].reset_index(drop=True)
```

results in

```
    asker1 que_text              date                    identifier
0    Peter      QQQ        14.10.2001                 Drs_2_00028_1
1   Markus      RRR  12. October 1999                 Drs_2_00029_1
2  Rebecca  GGG GGG        14.10.2004  Drs_2_00030_1_KlAnfr_000.tif
3    Sofie     None        14.10.2010                 Drs_2_00052_1
4    Jesus  WWW AAA        14.10.2000  Drs_2_00054_1_KlAnfr_000.tif
```

Some explanations:

- First step is to build a `mask` and extract into `df3` the data needed to work on.
- Then add 2 columns to `df3` by extracting from the column `identifier` the first part which identifies the grouping (-> `ID`) and the numbers (-> `No`).
- Afterwards `groupby` the `ID` column, merge the `que_text` entries, and replace the original `que_text` column in `df2` with the merged one.
- Finally drop all rows in which the value of the `identifier` column matches the pattern but the number-part isn't `'000'`.

---

Alternative approach:

```
def merge_qts(sdf):
    if sdf.shape[0] > 1:
        sdf.que_text.iat[0] = " ".join(
            qt for _, qt in sorted(zip(sdf.No, sdf.que_text))
            if qt is not None
        )
    return sdf.iloc[0, :]

pattern = r"^(.*?_KlAnfr)_(\d{3}).tif$"
df2[["ID", "No"]] = df2.identifier.str.extract(pattern)
df2.ID[df2.ID.isna()] = range(df2.ID.isna().sum())
df2 = (
    df2.groupby("ID", as_index=False, sort=False)
       .apply(merge_qts)
       .drop(columns=["ID", "No"])
)
```

Comment: Very well, you understood me correctly, if i understand your explanation correctly. Unfortunately there are some `None` values that are not excepted by your code, that is why at `sdf.que_text = " ".join(qt for _, qt in sorted(zip(sdf.No, sdf.que_text))` it throws `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, NoneType found`

Comment: @id345678 Thanks for the feedback. I see, those are _real_ `None`s. I your sample you did provide `'None'`, which is a string. I've updated the answer, maybe it works better now.

Comment: Perfect, it works very well. I have forgotten to add that i would like to drop `row 3,4,5,6,9` (the rows that contain the 2nd,3rd,... pages and identifier 001,002,...) after merging. How can i make this happen (ideally) within the last line of code?

Comment: @id345678 It would be easy if the rows you don't want are exactly those for which the value in `asker1` is `None`: `df2 = df2[~df2.asker1.isna()].reset_index(drop=True)`? (Seems to be the case in the sample, but maybe not in the whole dataframe.)

Comment: @id345678 Have you tried the edit of the answer I did some couple of minutes ago (at the end): Does that also not work?

Comment: Works very well now :) thanks. Do you want to include this valuable information in the question text or shall i edit? I assume you would express yourself more clearly to readers.

Comment: @id345678 Okay. I've just added an alternative that's based on the first solution.